# JSOUP gives weird output with URL

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am Using JSOUP to parse the HTML page and extract all text from it. Below code works fine with other URL's but this is giving weird output with this URL. http://gumgum-public.s3.amazonaws.com/numbers.html

```
    Document doc = null;
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://gumgum-public.s3.amazonaws.com/numbers.html").maxBodySize(0).get();
    String parsedText = doc.body().text();
    System.out.println("Output-"+parsedText);
```

Output-

```
Output-This is a test page

Output-This is a test page
```

HTML page contains large set of numbers. Please Help..

Thanks

Comment: The numbers have no html tag on the wanted page and your lib only reads content surrounded by html tags...

Comment: I thought of it but when I checked the same  URL with online JSOUP tutorial   http://try.jsoup.org/ . It extracted the numbers.

Comment: Because `http://try.jsoup.org/` automatically wraps the whole content in html tags.

Comment: So what are the options for me if I have to extract the text from such web pages.?

Comment: Surround it with a html tag? and then try to parse it...

Comment: I cant change that. Moreover, I tried with sample data as same page like this.  doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><head></head> <body><h1>This is test page.</h1> 3333333 33333333 55555 56666666 7777777777 88888888 88888888 8888888888 555555555555 3434545345 5345364353 6443443345 345353 34563434 357453234 </body></html>");   then it worked properly. I suppose it is issue with size of content.

Comment: And the result with that trial was?

Comment: Output-This is test page. 3333333 33333333 55555 56666666 7777777777 88888888 88888888 8888888888 555555555555 3434545345 5345364353 6443443345 345353 34563434 357453234

Comment: Ah your text was not displayed fully. So you may have to cut it in parts and concatenate it afterwards again...

Comment: I dont own that page. I have to parse such data. Are there any other ways to parse?

Answer (score 0):

Then your solution is the following:

1. Download the page
2. Slice it in smaller parts
3. Add a tag before and after
4. send the file to Jsoup
5. get your content.
6. Concat the parts

Comment: As you found out you have to slice it in smaller parts so jsoup can process it.